# YAHOO and BING support for Index, Image and Mobile sitemaps

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search-console, yahoo, bing-webmaster-tools

I know Google webmaster supports submitting Image, mobile, video and other types of sitemaps. YAHOO also mentions about mobile site map [here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/uk/yahoo/mobile/search/mobilewebtips.html). But does it support Image and video sitemaps.

I could not find if BING supports any of these types other than XML sitemaps. Can someone please point me to any documentation on submitting Index, Image and Mobile sitemaps.

Also does YAHOO and Bing support index sitemap files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Bing now powers all of Yahoo search (effectively), so you can stop considering submission to Yahoo
2. No, Bing - despite various [mentions](http://www.bing.com/community/webmaster/f/12252/p/647022/9539206.aspx#9539206) of it over the last two years, doesn't accept specific video sitemaps (mRSS) or anything beyond your normal XML
3. Yes, [Bing does support sitemap index files](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/support/Sitemaps.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Bing does accept video sites maps as well as media RSS feeds.   You can send email to bingfeed@microsoft.com with inquiries about how to submit video sitemap or feed

Answer (score 1):

Bing mentions support for mRSS in its "Webmaster Center Help":
http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/5/4/454C13D4-D94D-4B54-8E46-FE403DF7632B/WMC_FAQ.pdf